# How can I get the current tag name or commit id in Git?

Tags: git

I'm writing a bash script for release automation, and it needs to be run on a branch. If that's not the case, I want to print a helpful error message.

How can I test if 1) it's running on a branch or a *detached HEAD*, and if a detached HEAD, to 2) print the symbolic (tag) name, or commit id otherwise?

`git symbolic-ref HEAD` will solve point (1) above, but what about getting the symbolic (tag) name?

Edit: In case there are multiple tags, getting any tag name is acceptable.

Comment: What should it do if you have more than one tags?

Comment: `git log --format=oneline HEAD | awk '{print $1}'` should give you the commit id

Comment: `git rev-list -1 HEAD` could also be used to get the commit ID